# Chrome extension who modify html with "if", "add" command

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm not a skillful coder, that's why my explanation is going to be easy and basic.

I want to make a personal Google Chrome extension that makes HTML changes in a web page i don't own. I don't care if it's non-optimized or ugly code. I just want to make it work. Write a lot, don't fear me.

The code have to detects the variable "title="xxxx", and then it will add a change to the code.

For example, if:

```
<h2>
<a href="/car/bmw" class="secondaryPageLink" title="BMW's page">BMW</a>
</h2>

<div class="age">
<p>2005</p>
```

Then it's replaced with:

```
<h2>
<a href="/car/bmw" class="secondaryPageLink" title="BMW's page">BMW</a>
</h2>

<div class="age">
<p>250000,00$</p>
<p>2005</p>
```

if:

```
<h2>
<a href="/car/mercedes" class="secondaryPageLink" title="Mercedes's page">Mercedes</a>
</h2>

<div class="age">
<p>1987</p>
```

Then it's replaced with:

```
<h2>
<a href="/car/mercedes" class="secondaryPageLink" title="Mercedes's page">Mercedes</a>
</h2>

<div class="age">
<p>750000,00$</p>
<p>1987</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you will need the following files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Personal Extension",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Replaces HTML with something.",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }]
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
// Using a regular expression here to avoid case sensitivity problems,
// and to match for line breaks and whitespace after <div class="age">
var str1 = /<div class="age">\s*?<p>2005<\/p>/gi,
    str2 = '<div class="age"><p>250000$</p><p>2005</p>';

// We don't really want to deal with frames...
if (document.body.nodeName === 'BODY') {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(str1, str2);
}
```

Here's a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAMFx/)** that works.

Place both of these files into a folder and use the "load unpacked extension" button in Chrome.

I guess it's fair to say: warning, this is a very crude solution. It's ugly and will probably break in some cases, but you said you don't care about code quality... so here it is.

Also, the HTML code you provide is invalid. It should be:

```
<div class="car">
<a title="bmw"></a>
```

And hopefully it gets closed with `</div>` somewhere later in the code.

### EDIT #1

Okay, you've updated the question. Try putting the following in the contentscript.js:

```
var titleNode, // placeholder for a title node we're going to look for
    priceNode, // placeholder for a price node we're going to create
    ageNode, // placeholder for an age node where we will append the price node
    carBrand,
    carPrices = { // you can also use an array...
        'bmw': 250000,
        'mercedes': 300000
        // add more cars and prices here
    };

for (carBrand in carPrices) {
    // Don't look down the object's prototype chain:
    if (carPrices.hasOwnProperty(carBrand)) {

        // Find a title node that's inside a <div class="car">,
        // and has a title we're looking for in this iteration:
        titleNode = document.querySelector('div.car>a[title=' +
            carBrand + ']');

        // Make sure the title node is found and that it has a parent:
        if (titleNode && titleNode.parentNode) {
            // Find the age node:
            ageNode = titleNode.parentNode.querySelector('div.age');
            // Check if the <div class="age"> node is really there:
            if (ageNode) {
                priceNode = document.createElement('p');
                priceNode.innerHTML = carPrices[carBrand] + '$';
                ageNode.appendChild(priceNode);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the **[updated jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UAMFx/4/)**.

### EDIT #2

Try looking at the code provided above and reading documentation on various functions that are used. You will never learn otherwise...

If you read documentation on [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) you will figure out that to find a title node you can modify the above code as follows:

```
titleNode = document.querySelector('h2>a[title="BMW\'s page"]');
```

... or to find by pure brand name that can be found in the `href` attribute:

```
titleNode = document.querySelector('h2>a[href$="bmw"]');
```

Then to find the age node, you can look up its parent and the next element of the parent:

```
ageNode = titleNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
```

Here's a **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UAMFx/5/)** that demonstrates it.

Also, once again your HTML is incorrect. You haven't properly closed the `<h2></h2>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please note I have updated my first post, how you can help me with this next issue ? Thanks again.

Comment: @GoldMath Updated the answer. If it helps you, don't forget to upvote and accept as a correct answer to help other people with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I have tried adapt your code to the website but I fail, I have updated the first post with precise on the situation, thanks again.

Comment: Yeah ! I make it's work ! Now i'm gonna tweak it for fun. Thanks again ! Problem solve !

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in html. It has to be done with an actual programming language that can handle looping structures. html is purely framework code. It doesn't support conditional statements. Unfortunately, you probably wouldn't be able to grasp the concepts of a programming language at this point. I'd advise you to get familiar with html and css first. Build some simple static webpages with them that just show off content, and then work your way up and start adding functions like the one you're talking about using a programming language.

Comment: "It doesn't support conditional statements." ahem, ahem, of course you're right, but don't forget about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx